# How do I parse XML data with xmlbeans?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xmlbeans

I want to parse xml data using xmlbeans and store it into objects,The following is the  xml file, I want to parse it, I have model I just want to store all data into model objects,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<data:events>
    <data:event>
        <data:name>test</data:name>
        <data:date>2013-05-20-04:00</data:date>
        <data:track>
            <data:name>test</data:name>
            <data:race>
                <data:raceNumber>1</data:raceNumber>
                <data:postTimeDisplay>5:25 PM</data:postTimeDisplay>
                <data:runner>
                    <data:programNumber>1</data:programNumber>
                    <data:ownerName>user</data:ownerName>
                </data:runner>
                <data:runner>
                    <data:programNumber>7</data:programNumber>
                    <data:ownerName>PP</data:ownerName>
                </data:runner>
            </data:race>
        </data:track>
    </data:event>
</data:events>
```

I tried and search lot for parsing the above data using xmlbeans but I didn't get proper solution for the same and I am quit new in xml data parsing,
Please have look this and suggest to parse this xml.

Answer (score 0):

So you dont want to use SAX / DOM parsers ?
For xmlbeans did you get chance to look at

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-beans1/
- http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/conGettingStartedwithXMLBeans.html

As you said you are new to parsing xml using java and If you want to use SAX/DOM go throug

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-oQ5D91TAk

Comment: Thanks for solution, really I don't want to use SAX/DOM parser.

Comment: I went through the above link, but I am not able to compile xsd format to generate java classes